# How to change state of a non-related component from a timer component in React

Tags: reactjs, timer, components, state

I have a Timer component that is started with a click of a button:

```
handleClick: function() {
        if (this.state.running == 0) {
          this.setState({running: 1});
          ReactDOM.render(<Timer start={Date.now()} round={0} />,document.getElementById('timer'));
        }
      },
      render: function() {
         return  (
              <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Začni simulacijo</button>  
         );
      }
```

this sets off the Timer which has a tick function that checks if it needs to update a table of values (also a React component)...this happens here:

```
tick: function(){

          round = Math.floor(this.state.elapsed / seasonParams.gameDayTime);
          if (round > this.state.round) {
            var result = config.pairs.filter(function( obj ) {
              return obj.round == round;
            });
            this.setState({elapsed: new Date() this.props.start,"round":round }); //this sets state of timer component

            //HERE I WOULD NEED TO ADD SET STATE OF THE TABLE COMPONENT
          } 

          console.log("elapsed: "+this.state.elapsed+", round: "+round);
      },
```

The Table component accepts an array of object to render the table...but is not related to the Timer or Button component. How do I pass the newly found data to it in the Timer?

Thank you...

Comment: If you are using `redux`, you can dispatch an action from the timer component and update the Table component based on the new state.

Comment: Not using redux at the moment...